# Proper way to call a function of one component from another component

Tags: angular, angular5

I have two components.

**Component 1** is a little FAB menu icon thing that CALLS the function

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-contextualmenu',
templateUrl: './contextualmenu.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./contextualmenu.component.scss']
})
export class ContextualMenuComponent implements OnInit {
context: string;    

constructor(private ctxMenu: ContextualMenuSyncService, ) {
    ctxMenu.context$.subscribe(v => { this.context = v; });
}

ngOnInit() {}

add() {
    this.ctxMenu.add();
}
}
```

**Component 2** is a component that has the function being CALLED

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-sites',
templateUrl: './sites.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./sites.component.scss']
})
export class SitesComponent implements OnInit {
list: Site[];

constructor(private ctxMenu: ContextualMenuSyncService) {
    this.ctxMenu.sync("sites");
    this.ctxMenu.add = this.add;
}

ngOnInit() {   }

add() {       
    this.router.navigateByUrl("/newsite");
}
}
```

Lastly there is a **ContextualMenuSyncService** that acts a conduit between two components.

```
@Injectable()
export class ContextualMenuSyncService {
private context = new Subject<string>();
context$ = this.context.asObservable();

add: Function;

constructor() { }

sync(value: string) {
    this.context.next(value);
}
}
```

So in a nutshell I am trying to call `add()` of **Component 2** from `add()` of **Component 1**

According to what I have read on this topic a shared service as above is an appropriate way to accomplish inter-component communication.

My problem however is that when I call `add()` it is being executed out of `ContextualMenuSyncService` context. Meaning the `this` is `ContextualMenuSyncService` and not `SitesComponent` (**Component 2**) which means I have no access to `SitesComponent` (**Component 2**) members, injects, info, etc.

How do you call a member function of a component from another component within first component's context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to explicitly bind the `this` value of `add` to get Component 2's `this` value. There's several ways of doing this, but among the easiest and most popular is to use an **arrow function** like so when adding `add` to `ctxMenu`:

```
this.ctxMenu.add = () => this.add(); // maintains Component2's this
```

Alternatively, you could use `bind` like so:

```
this.ctxMenu.add = this.add.bind(this); // maintains Component2's this
```

Comment: Can I have a follow up to that. What if the function has a parameter? If I do `this.simpleSearch.searchFunction = () => this.search();` I get signatures don't match because `this.search()` is actually defined as `search(term)`. But if I do `this.simpleSearch.searchFunction = () => this.search(term);` it complains that it doesn't know what `term` is.

Answer (score 0):

You'd do it more like this:

Component where function is running:

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-sites',
templateUrl: './sites.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./sites.component.scss']
})
export class SitesComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
list: Site[];
private addSub;

constructor(private ctxMenu: ContextualMenuSyncService) {
    this.ctxMenu.sync("sites");
    this.addSub = this.ctxMenu.add$.subscribe(() => this.add());
}

ngOnInit() {   }

ngOnDestroy() { this.addSub.unsubscribe(); } // always unsubscribe

add() {       
    this.router.navigateByUrl("/newsite");
}
}
```

Service:

```
@Injectable()
export class ContextualMenuSyncService {
private context = new Subject<string>();
context$ = this.context.asObservable();

private addSource: Subject<any> = new Subject();
add$: Observable<any> = this.addSource.asObservable();
add() {
    this.addSource.next();
}

constructor() { }

sync(value: string) {
    this.context.next(value);
}
}
```

the function calling the service is fine.